# orchard - click on screen and will display widget etc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I remember seeing this in a tutorial but cant remember how to access it.

Using Orchard you can d/l something from the moudles/gallary that when viewing the website you can select anywhere on screen and it will tell you what widget and layer it is on (on the bottom of the screen)

was it designer tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Enable the Shape Tracing feature from the Designer Tools module. See http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Customizing-Orchard-using-Designer-Helper-Tools for details.